# Does installing things into /usr instead of /usr/local break things when upgrading to new version of Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, filesystem, cmake

I've installed some new software, e.g., sshlib, by following the respective tutorials.

Some of the tutorials rely on CMake and guide the user to use the default setting, i.e., install into /usr.

Reading Linux related articles, it is mentioned that installing into /usr can break things?

Have I done anything wrong by using the CMake default setting for install base directory (/usr)?

Answer (score 3):

Installing software from source and using `/usr` as prefix can break things, as you might overwrite libraries or binaries that are shipped with your distribution. These libraries and/or binaries often are dependencies for other programs and might prevent them from working correctly.

Best options to install things are:

- */usr/local* as prefix in the `configure` command
- */opt/* for binary distributed applications or if you have to e.g. maintain multi-version self compiled software

Comment: Where is it best to install programs? I thought we should put them all in /usr/lib but they are all broken when I do that :(